# Is variation the same as variance?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics, definition

**In population statistics, are variation and variance the same terms? If not, what is the difference between the two?**

I know that variance is the square of standard deviation. I also know that it is a measure of how sparse the data is, and I know how to compute it.

However, I've been following a Coursera.org course called "Model Thinking", and the lecturer clearly described variance but was constantly calling it variation. That got me confused a bit.

To be fair, he always talked about computing variation of some particular instance in a population.

Could someone make it clear to me if those are interchangeable, or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: `Variation`, unlike `variance`, is not the name of some specific quantity (however, `Coefficient of variation` is). It is a generic term, like `variability`. It is just `amount of variability` which can be measured by various quantities (most popular of them being `variance`).

Comment: So basically you are saying that `Variance` is a real statistical term with a formal model standing behind it, but `variation` is just a word describing relation between expected & real data?

Comment: Right - I changed that :)

Comment: Variance has a formula. Variation has no one formula, it is a generic term. Both variance and variation can be 1) a statistic describing a sample, 2) a parameter describing a population, 3) a statistic as an estimate of the correstonding parameter

Comment: Another analogue here is "spread." There isn't a formal equation for calculating "spread," although it's appropriate to say that "variance" is a measure of "spread." I think in this context "spread" and "variation" are equivalent.

Comment: Variation reveals just only the dispersion of the values from their center. Where as variance quantifies the dispersion of the values from their center

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a full wikipedia article discussing this topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion

As described by others in the comments here, the short answer is: no, variation $\ne$ variance. Synonyms for "variation" are spread, dispersion, scatter and variability. It's just a way of talking about the behavior of the data in a general sense as either having a lot of density over a narrow interval (generally near the mean, but not necessarily if the distribution is skewed) or spread out over a wide range. Variance is a particular measure of variability, but others exist (and several are enumerated in the linked article).

Comment: but it is used interchangeably by Andrew Ng in this video https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/S1bq1/choosing-the-number-of-principal-components

Comment: Nice. See also "centrality" versus "mean", etc. :)

Answer (score 14):

`Variation` may be understood best as a general term for a class of different concepts, of which [variance](/questions/tagged/variance) $(\sigma^2)$ is only one. [Levine and Roos <sup>(1997)</sup>](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Emss/data%20analysis/Volume%20I%20pdf%20/074%20Description%20%20Numb%20for.pdf) also consider [standard-deviation](/questions/tagged/standard-deviation) $(\sigma)$ a `variation` concept, among others.

To demonstrate why the distinction might be important, compare also the [coefficient-of-variation](/questions/tagged/coefficient-of-variation) [$(\frac\sigma\mu)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Definition), and the mathematical concept, `total variation`, which has [several definitions unto itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Definitions). Then there are all manners of [qualitative variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualitative_variation), which are mentioned in the Wikipedia article @DavidMarx linked. These pages corroborate his answer BTW; `statistical dispersion` or `variability` are better synonyms for `variation` than `variance`, which is clearly not so synonymous.

BTW, [here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Total_variation.gif) a cool GIF of one kind of `total variation`: the length of the path on the $y$ axis that the red ball travels.

[image]

Definitely not the same as `variance`!

<sub>**Reference**

Levine, J. H., & Roos, T. B. (1997). Description: Numbers for the variation. *Introduction to data analysis: The rules of evidence* (Volume I:074). Dartmouth College. Retrieved from [http://www.dartmouth.edu/~mss/data%20analysis/Volume%20I%20pdf%20/074%20Description%20%20Numb%20for.pdf](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Emss/data%20analysis/Volume%20I%20pdf%20/074%20Description%20%20Numb%20for.pdf)</sub>